# React Environment Variable undefined inside docker nginx

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx

I have a env variable name: REACT_APP_BACKEND in my react app.
I'm able **to build** my app and run it successfully in nginx in my macos.

When I try to run it inside docker and nginx, I pass list of environment variables with `--env-file=.env` command. However this env variable is undefined in the browser, even though when I entered the running docker instance I'm able to echo this variable successfully.

```
/ # echo $REACT_APP_BACKEND
http://localhost:3000
/ #
```

I don't know if I missing somethings in docker settings, nginx settings or my build command?

This is the nginx settings (nginx.conf):

```
server {
  listen       80;
  location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }
}
```

This is docker config:

```
#... installing node and npm install#

RUN npm run build 

### STAGE 2: Production Environment ###
FROM nginx:1.12.0-alpine
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Comment: This is exactly how it's meant to work. Your browser is on a different machine (potentially) and cannot access the node server's environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that problem is is from build command, When running `npm run build`, npm **replaces** all occurrences of environment variables with the values that it can find in `.env` or `.env.production` files in the same directory.

In my case, `.env` file was not in the same root.

Comment: In my case I had ran the build command before creating the .env file